# Access functions of a module from another module which itself imports the first module

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, importerror

Sorry for the confusing title, I tried to fit as much of the problem in the title.

---

#### The scenario:

I have a module(say `ModuleA`) which contains class definitions of some Tkinter GUI elements.
These elements also have certain events/functions bound/binded with them(such as `'<Button-1>','<Button-2>'...`.

Now there's another module(say `ModuleB`). This is the main(core of the) program. In this module I import `ModuleA` to use its objects. The objects of `ModuleA` have a place in an array(say `Array1`); and also there is another array(say `Array2`) which stores the value of just one of the data-member of each of the objects of `Array1`, and these are the data-members which are manipulated by the `Event Bindings`.

So the problem is that when an `Event` occurs, the objects(stored in `Array1`) of `ModuleA` respond visually as needed, but in the backend their corresponding data-member values must also be updated in `Array2` accordingly.

---

#### In short:

```
#ModuleA.py

from ModuleB import foo

class bar
    data = 1
    # some tkinter code 
    # bind mouse click to function foo of ModuleB
    
-------------------------------------------------------

#ModuleB.py

from ModuleA import bar

Array1 = [objects of class bar]
Array2 = [value of data of objects in Array1]

def foo(#obj of class bar)
    # find index of bar object which called this function in Array1
    # accordingly change Array2
```

---

#### What I tried:

In the `Event Bindings` of the objects of `ModuleA` I added the required function(say `foo`) which will handle the required array manipulations and is defined in `ModuleB` as it has to handle the `Array2` of `ModuleB`.
But this gave me an error `global name 'foo' is not defined`

So in the class-definition of `ModuleA` I added `global foo`, which too didn't solve it.

Finally I tried inserting in `ModuleA`

```
from ModuleB import foo
```

Which raised an `ImportError` saying it cannot import foo(which I guess is because `ModuleB` itself is importing `ModuleA` hence circular reference)

---

#### A solution

One solution clearly visible is to copy entire `ModuleA` (containing class definitions) to `ModuleB`.
But this is not always practical and not too pythonic either.

Please help.

Comment: Hi, I understood that you imported ModuleA into ModuleB , then also you imported ModuleB into ModuleA . If you did this obviously you will get import error. 
It is always not possible to import like that

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are doing wrong ,  for suppose take two modules 
moduleA and moduleB. If you import moduleA into the moduleB then you can't import the 
moduleB into moduleA if you are trying to do that thing you should get Import error.

let see The wrong way that you  are doing

The below one is moduleA.py

```
import moduleB
print " I am moduleA"
class foo():
     pass
```

here is the moduleB.py

```
from  moduleA import foo
print "I am moduleB"
```

now  execute moduleB.py

```
python moduleB.py
```

you will get the ImportError , but  it would not happened if you do

```
python moduleA.py
```

The above process is quit wrong, python will not allow this type of importing 
simply here we are creating loop of imports because on each first import the top level code of whole module will be executed of course python will not allow this .

To solve your problem just change the module hierarchy .

Here is the simple solution :
If you want the content of both modules (moduleA and moduleB) just create one more module 
moduleC and import both modules(moduleA and moduleB) there in moduleC and do your necessary stuff.

Please refer the edited stuff , you are doing same thing

Comment: @aditya : you can create this type of ImportError by simple example that I have described in my answer

Comment: Um, did you test the example you gave? Circular imports are legal in Python (though usually discouraged, since they're confusing). You'll only have problems if one of the modules refers to contents of the other module at its top level (including `from mod_a import foo`). If you just import the module `import mod_a`) and all the references are within functions or methods that don't get called immediately, there often are not any problems.

Comment: @aditya: please figure out the edited example , if we import the module directly we will not get ImportError in circular import , but it is not possible to import top level things like from .. import ..
please refer the edited example you will able to create a 
ImportError when executing the moduleB.py

Comment: I've edited the question, and I don't import entire modules, just the class definition(which has no reference to `ModuleA` other than the binded function `foo`) from `ModuleA` to `ModuleB`, and the function `foo`(which also has no reference to class `bar`) from `ModuleB` to `ModuleA`

Answer (score 1):

Circular imports in Python can be confusing. It's easy to get it wrong, and so it's usually best to avoid them, if possible. However, they are not illegal, and if you're careful they can work just fine.

The import process works like this, when you type `import foo`:

1. First, Python checks in the `sys.modules` dictionary to see if the module `foo` has been loaded already. If so, the pre-existing module is simply placed into your current module's namespace (and the process stops there).
2. If not, it checks if `foo.py` file can be found to load. If none exists, an `ImportError` is raised and the process stops.
3. If a file was found, a new, empty module object is created and put into `sys.modules` under the name `foo`.
4. Then, Python opens the file and begins executing it, using the module object created in step 3 as the local namespace.

Now, if the `foo` module described above has it's own `import` statements, the import process can recurse, loading up the other module before continuing on with the execution of the `foo` module's code. But, since the empty module object get added to the `sys.modules` dictionary before any more imports are processed, it will never loop all the way around and try to load the same file more than once (in most cases).

There are a few things that can go wrong.

If `foo` is being executed as a script (rather than being imported by some other module), it's initial entry in `sys.modules` will be under the name `__main__` rather than `foo`. This means that if `foo` gets imported from somewhere else, you'll end up with two copies of the same code. This is an exception to the general rule that a module doesn't get loaded twice, and it can catch you off guard in some cases.

Also, if your circularly imported modules are making top-level accesses to each other, you'll run into trouble if they're imported in the wrong order (or any order, if they both reference each others contents in the wrong way from the top level). You can avoid most problems by ensuring that as little code runs at module load time as possible (put it into functions instead!). Then call the functions from a well defined entry point, after everything has been loaded.

So, in your situation, here are things I'd examine:

1. Do you need to be doing `from moduleB import foo`? Can you instead do`import moduleB` and access `moduleB.foo` later on? This would be the easiest fix that could work (though it will not fix all possible problems).
2. Do you need to be doing work at the top level of your modules? Often you can put object creation into a factory function, rather than at top level (which makes solution #1 work more often). This can be a good design idea anyway, since it is easier to extend later if you want to be able to alter (or customize) the way they objects are created at run time (you just write a second function that works differently, or add arguments to the factory).
3. Can you move a part of the code from `ModuleA` or `ModuleB` into a third module, which doesn't need to import either of them, and so eliminate the need for the circular import? This is often a good idea, as it lets you sidestep the whole issue of what gets loaded when.

**Edit**: here's what a fixed version of your modules might look like:

ModuleA.py:

```
import ModuleB

class bar():
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        # do something here that accesses ModuleB.foo
```

ModuleB.py:

```
import ModuleA

def foo():
    # do whatever

Array1 = [ModuleA.bar(i) for i in range(10)]
Array2 = [whatever]
```

main.py:

```
import ModuleB # import order is important here!
import ModuleA

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # do stuff
```

This should be the minimal fix. ModuleA only accesses `ModuleB.foo` from within the `bar` class's `__init__` method, so the circular imports will work OK as long as `ModuleB.foo` is defined before any `bar` instances are created.

If you want the imports to work in any order, it's a bit trickier. You don't want any work being done at the top-level of the modules:

ModuleA.py is as above.

ModuleB.py:

```
import ModuleA

def foo():
    #do stuff

def setupArrays():
    global Array1, Array2 # lets us create these global variables

    Array1 = [ModuleA.bar(i) for i in range(10)]
    Array2 = [whatever]
```

main.py:

```
import ModuleA, ModuleB  # import order doesn't matter

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ModuleB.setupArrays()
    # do stuff
```

This is still a bit of a kludge. If you can break the circular import completely, perhaps the code can be simplified in a more obvious way. For instance, we could pass the callback function as a parameter to the `bar` class's constructor:

ModuleA.py:

```
# No import statement here! Circular imports avoided!

class bar():
    def __init__(self, data, callback):
        self.data = data
        # bind stuff to call the callback function provided
```

ModuleB:

```
import ModuleA

def foo():
    # do whatever

Array1 = [ModuleA.bar(i, foo) for i in range(10)]
Array2 = [whatever]
```

Comment: The first solution doesn't work and I didn't quite get the others one too; do you mean to say that I `define` the class within a function by itself. I have edited the question to incorporate an example

Comment: Given the example code you've shown, I think importing the modules by name should work. Just do `import ModuleA` and `import ModuleB`, then refer to `foo` and `bar` with the module they're from prefixed. This will probably fix things. You don't need to put your class definitions into a function, just make sure that the places where the `bar` class references `ModuleB.foo` is inside a method (such as `__init__`). I'll update the answer with some more specific examples of how you may be able to fix stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You should check this link out : http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm
There is an interesting paragraph about how to handle circular reference by moving the import statement at the end of the module. But IMHO don't try to handle that thing, just refactor your code ;)